# Grub Installation Problem using Ubuntu Mini ISO

Tags: boot, grub2, ubuntu-minimal

I have a problem when using the Ubuntu Mini ISO. It defaults installing grub on /dev/sda but that's my USB Flash where I'm installing Ubuntu from. How can I change that to /dev/sdb which is my actual drive? There is no option that I can change this.

Comment: If it's just grub you could try [installing it](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html) yourself...

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed Ubuntu yet, You could also use the advanced option during the installation process and select the target device for the bootloader as /dev/sdb (which is your hard disk). You will have to configure the other options too, but I don't think you will have a problem in configuring them. A simple google search for each option will present you with adequate information to install properly. Tip: Keep swap at 2gb. More than enough.